# Gregorian Calendar returning strange values?

Tags: java, calendar

```
public class MyCalendar {

    GregorianCalendar greg = new GregorianCalendar();
    String[] month = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    String[] day = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

    public void printMonth(int d, int m, int y) {
    GregorianCalendar greg= new GregorianCalendar(greg.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                greg.get(Calendar.MONTH), 1);

            System.out.println(month[greg.get(Calendar.MONTH)]);
            System.out.println(greg.get(Calendar.FRIDAY));
            System.out.println(greg.get(Calendar.SATURDAY));
    }
```

I'm having trouble figuring out why greg.get(Calendar._____) is giving me unexpected values.

```
YEAR, MONTH, DATE all give me correct values: 2015, 9, 6

FRIDAY returns 279

SATURDAY returns 3

SUNDAY returns 2015

TUESDAY returns 41
```

Could someone explain to me why I'm getting these numbers? I was trying to find out how to the date for all Saturdays of the month and thought `greg.get(Calendar.SATURDAY)` might have been useful in doing so.

Comment: That's not really how you're suppose to use `get`, your suppose to use something like `Calendar.DATE` for the date value or `Calendar.YEAR` for the year value, for example.  So using `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` will return a value which can be matched to `Calendar.MONDAY` through `Calendar.SUNDAY`

Comment: Oh and if you're using Java 8, make use of the new Time API or just use Joda Time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, `Calendar#get` allows you to get a paritcular field of the `Calendar` object, such as `DAY_OF_WEEK`, which can then be mapped back to `Calendar.MONDAY` through `Calendar.SUNDAY` to make it simpler to understand the return result.

So, to count the number of `SATURDAY`s in a month, you will need to first find the first `SATURDAY` (and yes, I tried using `cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SATUDAY)` after setting the `DATE`, but it gave inconsistent results)

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);

while (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY) {
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
```

And then simply count forward 7 days until we leave the current month

```
int count = 0;
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
while (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month) {
    count++;
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
}

System.out.println("This month has " + count + " saturdays");
```

## Java 8

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate endOfMonth = date.withDayOfMonth(date.lengthOfMonth());

date = date.withDayOfMonth(1);
System.out.println(date);
date = date.with(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, DayOfWeek.SATURDAY.getValue());

int count = 0;
while (date.isEqual(endOfMonth) || date.isBefore(endOfMonth)) {
    count++;
    date = date.plusDays(7);
}

System.out.println("You have " + count + " Saturdays");
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps me understand a bit better. First time trying to work with Calendar/GregorianCalendar. Not as easy or straight forward as I thought it would be.

Comment: Oh, and unless you have a particular reason to use a `GregorianCalendar`, it would be better to use `Calendar.getInstance`

Comment: I just came across this on coderanch: "All Calendar.getInstance() does is create a new GregorianCalendar object with the default zone and locale.
" I guess that means I should just use Calendar.getInstance() for this assignment?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on that been the case, as some local's might use different `Calendar` implementations